# Jtable does not refresh after inserting a new data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Here iam trying to search prodcuts from jtable.But the problem is,the new search results getting added under previous search results and not updating jtable even i used **fireTableDataChanged()** method.

Here is my code

```
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


       System.out.println("Im in createIban with the values: " +comboBox.getSelectedItem()+ " and " + textField.getText());
      if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Serial No"))
      {
            System.out.println("0");
           String cmb=textField.getText().toString();

 try{
      con=    (Connection) Connect.ConnectDB();

      String sql="select * from stocks where serial=?";
      pst =   (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1, cmb);
      rs=pst.executeQuery();

      model = (DefaultTableModel) jt.getModel(); 

      model.fireTableDataChanged();            **//Here i used the method**


  while(rs.next()) {

            dt = rs.getString("date");
            mdt = rs.getString("mdate");
            srn = rs.getString("serial");
            mod = rs.getString("model");

            cap = rs.getString("capacity");
            inv = rs.getString("invoice");
            amt = rs.getString("amount");

            int i;
            for(i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++){
                {}
            }
          jt.repaint();
          model.fireTableDataChanged();       **//Here i used the method**
          model.addRow(new Object[]{i+1,mod,cap,dt,mdt,srn,inv,amt}); 


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Succesfully stored","User",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
  }     catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   catch(SQLException ex){
       System.out.print(ex);

    }
```

Comment: Your ActionListener code should *not* be calling model's `fireTableDataChanged()` method. Rather your TableModel itself should call this method inside of its `addRow(...)` method. Since you're using a DefaultTableModel, you know that its `addRow(...)` method already does this, which suggests that you still need to do some debugging to figure out why things are not working.

Comment: So you says DefaultTableModel does not need any extra method to update a table?.Then why my table does not update automatically.How i can debug it.

Comment: Use a debugger or logging to see if data is actually being extracted from the database and if it is being in fact added to the table model. Make sure that you're working with the model from the actual displayed JTable and not some other table,... you've got more work to do. Also, when posting code here, please strive to make sure that your code's formatting is appropriate. Your random use of indentation makes it very hard to fully understand your code.

Comment: I think you can help me better than a debugging.so i will explain my code,it is nothing..there is a jtable with product details(full products in databse),and a button to search.when i press search button a custom dialogue box with combobox and a textfiled and a submit button will come,my code starts from here(when i hit submit button).

Comment: Myself, I'd help better if you could create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), a ***minimal*** (i.e., very small) program that we can run unaltered and that shows your error for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai guys finally i found a solution for that,it will be very use full for the people who seeking this type of question's answer,so i would like to post my code here

just make a method called reset()
inside that

```
  DefaultTableModel model;
  model = (DefaultTableModel) jtable1.getModel(); 

void reset()
 {
for(int i=model.getRowCount()-1; i>=0;i--)
{
    model.removeRow(i);
 }
 }
```

And call this reset method anywhere you want,it will be work fine with simple codes,good luck